# Program seems to ignore synchronized() line

Tags: java, synchronized

I was having difficulties with an ArrayList that I ultimately determined could only be caused by synchronization failure. Which I found hard to believe, as I had coded my program to make sure manipulations of the ArrayList were properly synchronized.

I've created a solution, but I have no idea why it works when the original code did not.

This is generally how the arrangement looked to begin with.

```
public class MasterClass {

    private ArrayList<SlaveClass> list;

    public MasterClass() {
        list = new ArrayList<SlaveClass>();
    }

    public synchronized Object conductOpperation() {
        //Numerous SlaveClasses are created here and executed.
        //Opperation returns it's result when all the SlaveClasses have finished their run.
    }

    private MasterClass master() {
        return this;
    }

    public class SlaveClass extends Thread {

        public SlaveClass() {
            list.add(this);
        }

        public void run() {
            //Code
            synchronized(master()){
                list.remove(this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The behavior of "evaluateList()" was extremely strange because, as I later found out, it wasn't synchronize locked when the SlaveClasses were completing their opperations and removing themselves from "list".

However, when I made this minor modification to the code:

```
public class MasterClass {

    private ArrayList<SlaveClass> list;

    public MasterClass() {
        list = new ArrayList<SlaveClass>();
    }

    public synchronized Object conductOpperation() {
        //Numerous SlaveClasses are created here and executed.
        //Opperation returns it's result when all the SlaveClasses have finished their run.
    }

    private MasterClass master() {
        return this;
    }

    private synchronized void removeSlave(SlaveClass s) {
        slave.remove(s);
    }

    public class SlaveClass extends Thread {

        public SlaveClass() {
            list.add(this);
        }

        public void run() {
            //Code
            synchronized(master()){
                removeSlave(this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

...suddenly all my synchronization problems stopped!

So why didn't the initial coding work to begin with?

Comment: I'm surprised that all your synchronization problems have stopped, given the unsynchronized `list.add(this)` in the SlaveClass constructor.

Comment: *FYI:* You don't need that `master()` method, since `MasterClass.this` can be used instead, e.g. `synchronized (MasterClass.this) { ... }`

Comment: Well, tbh, that comes down to my paraphrasing of the actual code. IRL, all the SlaveClasses were created in the same opperation that I've symbolized with "evaluateList()" here, so in actuality, they are synchronized.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think every Slave has it's own MasterClass.  You need to reference MasterClass with static methods and variables.  Also you use a threadsafe collection class.